# Write data in unknown encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, milter

Is it possible write data to a file in an unknown encoding?
I cannot decode email headers, for example message-id, because if I use handler ignore or a replace
https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers
non-RFC header will be RFC-compliant and antispam don't increase spam score.

I get string from postfix in milter protocol. I cannot save this data unchanged for antispam, raise UnicodeError. Examples:

cat savefile

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
fh = open('test', 'w+')
fh.write(sys.argv[1])
```

```
echo žlutý | xargs ./savefile && cat test
žlutý
```

```
echo žlutý | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ISO8859-2 - | xargs ./savefile 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/./savefile", line 5, in <module>
    fh.write(sys.argv[1])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcbe' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

Input may be a lot of unknown encoding. Milter application in python2 works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to handle raw `bytes` then, not strings. `open` the output file in binary mode. Note this:

> `sys.argv`
>
> ..
>
> **Note:** On Unix, command line arguments are passed by bytes from OS. Python decodes them with filesystem encoding and “surrogateescape” error handler. When you need original bytes, you can get it by `[os.fsencode(arg) for arg in sys.argv]`.
>
> <sub>https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv</sub>

So:

```
import sys
import os

with open('test', 'wb+') as fh:
    fh.write(os.fsencode(sys.argv[1]))
```